# Correctly using print in pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, spyder

I am running a simple example in pyspark that applies a reduceByKey to a given data:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").master("local[*]").getOrCreate()
data = [('Hello',1),('Hello',1),('Hello',1),('Bye',1), ('Bye',1)]
rdd = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(data)
mod_rdd = rdd.reduceByKey(lambda a,b: a+b)
results=mod_rdd.collect()
print(results)
```

However, my problem is that running this in spyder doesn't actually print the results although running it from anaconda prompt gives the expected result:

> [('Bye', 2), ('Hello', 3)]

I have also noticed that if I change my last two lines in the code to just:

```
print(mod_rdd.collect())
```

then print works both in spyder and in anaconda prompt. Why is this the case? Is there a way to fix this or shouls pyspark code always be runned in anaconda prompt?

In case it is necessary I am using spyder version 5.1.5 and python 3.9.7

Edit: I add the message I get:

> Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
> Setting default log level to "WARN".
> To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
> 21/11/30 16:18:53 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
> D:\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\shuffle.py:60: UserWarning: Please install psutil to have better support with spilling
> D:\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\shuffle.py:60: UserWarning: Please install psutil to have better support with spilling
> 21/11/30 16:19:08 WARN ProcfsMetricsGetter: Exception when trying to compute pagesize, as a result reporting of ProcessTree metrics is stopped
> D:\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\shuffle.py:60: UserWarning: Please install psutil to have better support with spilling
> D:\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\shuffle.py:60: UserWarning: Please install psutil to have better support with spilling
> D:\spark-3.2.0-bin-hadoop3.2\python\lib\pyspark.zip\pyspark\shuffle.py:60: UserWarning: Please install psutil to have better support with spilling

I get a bunch of warnings that ask me to install psutil. However after `pip install psutil` this has not been solved. Running the same thing in anaconda prompt also gives the warnings but the results variable is printed bellow them.

Comment: if I understand it correctly, spyder runs an IPython environment / console. And, it should ideally work exactly the same in both cases. what does it print on spyder in the first case if not expected result? have you checked the type of the var? _(should be a list after collect())_

Comment: @samkart If I do that I get that results is list type variable. I am going to edit the question to show the message I get

Comment: then there's nothing wrong with the variable, and my guess is it some spyder specific detail that's messed up. I ran your code piece on a jupyter notebook and it runs perfectly. Unfortunately, I'm not a spyder user and it seems this Q is out of my scope. __I suggest you add the [tag:spyder] tag to highlight it to its specific users__